# Integrate Paypal express option in OpenCart

Tags: paypal, opencart2.x

I'm workin on opencart 2.1.0.1 with custom design with Paypal express option install evrything is working good, but when go to site of payppal to pay your order the paypal show next to delyvery time price 4$ and collect this 4$ with total price. Can someone say me from where is this error . I think this thing happens because there is some mistake with база database.
See picture down.

[image: Here is screenshot of what I mean]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found from where is problem, it was in database.